# How to remove DASL filter text from Outlook status bar with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, filtering

I am filtering Outlook using DASL filters which is work fine. But when clearing the filters, filtered content get reset, but it will not show the number of emails at the bottom. It shows as "Filter applied". So I need to manually go and clear the DASL filter values.

Can we clear the DASL filter to the default by VBA without changing the existing view I am on?

For clear filter I use the same code in the posted answer. It clears the data. But it does not clear the text in the status bar and it keep showing "Filter applied".

[image: Screenshot of the status bar text after clear filter]

```
Public Sub FilterView()

    Dim objView As View
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    On Error Resume Next
        Set olMail = olApp.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olMail Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Set olMail = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    If Not olMail Is Nothing Then   
            SName = olMail.Sender
    Else
        MsgBox "Active item is not an email or no email selected"
    End If
    
    Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
    QueryV = "urn:schemas:mailheader:sender = " & Chr(39) & SName & Chr(39)
  
    objView.Filter = QueryV
    objView.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: What code do you use for filtering in Outlook? Do you apply filters to a folder view in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

The [View.Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.standard) property returns a boolean that specifies whether or not the view is a built-in Outlook view. So, if it is not standard you may always call the [View.Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.reset) method which resets a built-in Microsoft Outlook view to its original settings.

```
Sub ResetView() 
 Dim v as Outlook.View
 ' Save a reference to the current view object
 Set v = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
 ' Reset and then apply the current view 
 v.Reset 
 v.Apply 
End Sub
```

Also you may consider setting up the CurrentView in Outlook on your own by setting the [View.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.filter) property which returns or sets a string value that represents the filter for a view. For example:

```
Private Sub FilterViewToLastWeek() 
 Dim objView As View 
 ' Obtain a View object reference to the current view.
 Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView 
 ' Set a DASL filter string, using a DASL macro, to show
 ' only those items that were received last week. 
 objView.Filter = "%lastweek(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%" 
 
 ' Save and apply the view. 
 objView.Save 
 objView.Apply 
 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for clearing the status bar text. You may try refreshing the current view by selecting another folder pro grammatically and then returning back to the original folder.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just want a way to clear the filter text in the bottom of the outlook. Once applied the filter and clear it, it still says "Filter applied" in outlook status bar. Instead when cleat it should show number of emails and unread emails. I am using the same code as you have sent above to filter.

Comment: What code have you tried to clear the filter and apply your changes in Outlook?

Comment: To apply filter i am using

Comment: It is clear how a filter is applied, but the code which resets the view is absent.

Comment: Here is the code i have used to clear filter. It clear the filter. But it does not clear the filter text in the status bar. It keeps with the text "Filter applied" As per my screenshot in the first description. Anyway to reset the status bar text?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for clearing the status bar text.